# kql filter out same but capitalized records

Tags: filter, duplicates, kql, capitalization

I want to filter the same record with capital letters, like:

```
my.user@mydomain.com
My.USER@mydomain.com
```

I tried to filter with this

```
| where AccountName in~ ('my.user')
```

I want to filter to have only one record showing up.
Now I have two records for the same user, but only one is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can `summarize` by user and take just one value by using `max(AccountName)`

```
| summarize AccountName=max(AccountName) by user
```

Full example:

```
let T1=datatable(user:string, AccountName:string) [
  "Paul", "my.user@mydomain.com",
  "Paul", "My.USER@mydomain.com",
  "Eric", "email1@mail.com",
  "Petra", "email2@mail.com",
];
T1
| summarize AccountName=max(AccountName) by user
```

[image]